# Find unique values in map<string, vector<string>>?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a basic search function. Right now, I have the function to set up to accept three arguments: `map<string, vector<string>>`, `const string& key`, and `bool unique`.

My goal is to have `query` check if `key` is in the map, and if it is with `bool unique = false` just output all the values associated with the key, duplicates and all.

However, I need to also have the ability to output just the unique values associated with the key if `bool unique = true`

I have the latter part working exactly as a want it, but I'm struggling with outputting the unique values. How do I go about this? Is it possible to do so without creating a new vector or altering the map?

Apologies if anything is unclear, I'm happy to clarify if needed. Thank you.

```
void query(const map<string, vector<string>>& map, const string& key, bool unique) {

const auto pair = map.equal_range(key);
 if(map.count(key)){
    for( auto iter = pair.first ; iter != pair.second ; ++iter ){

        for( const auto& str : iter->second ) {

            if (!unique){
                cout << "  " << key << " ";
                cout << str << "\n";

            } else if (unique) {
                // output key + unique values
            } 
        }
    }
} else {
    cout << "<Not found>\n";

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a map. This only obfuscates things. Get rid of everything but a vector, and solve the problem of removing duplicate values from the vector. There are only so many basic ways to do it, the most basic one is iterating of a vector and using a temporary set (unordered_set) to keep track of the values already seen, and skipping over them, if they're encountered again. Simple, straightforward. Once you get that done, the rest of this is you've already done, so: mission accomplished.

Comment: Consider using `std::unique` from the algorithms header.